# How to make an array of color images in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, 3d, multidimensional-array

I want to make an array of color images in Matlab so I can do 
    thearray(i)
and get a color image. Is there a way to do this other than making an array of 3D arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br1zm43-1):

```
images = cell(100,1); 
% ... f.e. in a for loop: 
images{i} = rand(100,200);
% to query the image (2D array) again: 
myImage = images{n};
```